# Is there a group property for contacts gathering on Android Using Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I'm wondering if there is some way to select a group name from the contacts group on Android and send them all an sms at the same time. 
The properties found for the contact on Phonegap are: 
id, 
displayName, 
name, 
nickname,
phoneNubers,
emails,
addresses,
ims,
organizations,
birthday,
note,
photos,
categories,
urls.

Which don't contain Group, so is there another method to select a group ? Or Should I select all the desired contacts one by one every time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the group property on Android does not map to any of the fields in the W3C Contact API spec. If you want to group of bunch of contacts you may want to give them all the same note so you can find all contacts based on the note.

Comment: Thank you so much Simon, your answers are always very helpful =)